# How can I redirect pages with parameters to pages on an different domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I searched the forum and found some questions close to what I am trying to achieve but they don't work for what I am trying to do.

We got a new client and we need to redirect the pages of his old website to the new one.
All the pages in the old website have this structure:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=158&Itemid=179
```

I need to redirect each page to the relevant page of the new website. The structure of the urls in the new website is like this:

```
http://newdomain.website.com/slug/
```

I am assuming that the only way to do this is through htaccess but I cannot figure out how to write the command.

Thank u in advance for any help.

Comment: So new URL should be: `http://newdomain.website.com/slug/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=158&Itemid=179` ?

Comment: I need to be redirected. So if someone tries to access `http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=158&Itemid=179` will be redirected to `http://newdomain.website.com/slug/`

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.website.com/slug/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file on `domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://newdomain.website.com/slug/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=.+?&Itemid=.*?64$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://newdomain.website.com/slug/? [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=.+?&Itemid=.*?64$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.website.com/slug/? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: How should I set the query string in order to work? I have tried this:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=.+?)&Itemid=(.64*)$ [NC]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this condition: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=.+?)&Itemid=(.*?64.*)$ [NC]`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I have also tried by changing the second part from `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://newdomain.website.com/slug/? [L,NC,R=301]` to `RewriteRule ^$ http://newdomain.website.com/slug/? [R=301,L]` but still nothing.

Comment: For which URL it didn't work? Did you try to make this your very first rule?

Comment: I have tried the query you've given me `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=.+?)&Itemid=(.*?64.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://newdomain.website.com/slug/? [L,NC,R=301]` but it doesn't work. Then I tried also by modifying the second row but that didn't work either.
Do u think that the problem is caused due to the fact that each old url has two ids? This is the url of the page I am trying to redirect: `http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=156&Itemid=64`

Comment: see edited answer and **make sure this is your very first rule** in your root .htaccess

Comment: It is the first rule in my file. I have tried the edited version but it still doesn't work.

Comment: "Just for testing" if you comment out `RewriteCond` above does it then redirect to newdomain?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47265/discussion-between-kat-indo-and-anubhava)

Comment: The edited solution is working but i doesn't redirect to the url I point it to. I checked if there's any cache plugin used but there isn't, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You can easily test caching is there or not. Put same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not for the URL of `http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=156&Itemid=6‌​4`

Comment: It doesn't generate, so probably there's a cache somewhere.

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to convey.